# SCNSkinner.boneIndices access generates GBytes of memory allocation - why?

Tags: macos, memory, scenekit, scnskinner

I have an app that analyses the bones influence over vertices. For this I go through a `SCNSkinner` `boneIndices` data in a loop, and, though I don't allocate memory inside this loop, GBytes of memories are allocated, resulting in a crash of the app.

I have traced crashes to be linked to access to `boneIndices` using Instruments the following way:

1. See that memory is being allocated in a crazy way (here, 15GBytes in about 5 seconds):
   [image]
2. Click on this "Malloc 224k" to see that they are all performed in a single method.
   [image]
3. Click on the method name, and the tools clearly blames access to `.boneIndices`.
   [image]

As you can notice, this is Objective-C code (this is a category on SCNSkinner), but I observed the same with a Swift translation.

Why is every read access to SCNSkinner.boneIndices (read only) generating some memory allocation ?

What is the trick to avoid that ?
(basically I only want to read that buffer).

PS1: I observed that on macOS 14.2.1 - I haven't verified on iOS.

PS2: You can also see that an access to .bones generated 352 bytes of allocation, which I can easily live with, but still, it is surprising that accessing SCNSkinner properties to read them generates so much allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving a skinner's `bones` or `boneIndices` is likely returning autoreleased `NSArray` instances. If done in a tight loop this can lead to important memory pressure as reported here by Instruments.

The fix is simple: store `self.boneIndices` in a local variable before the nested loops so that there's only 1 `NSArray` allocation.

Comment: Indeed, storing self.boneIndices before the loop solved everything - thanks fo that. I still wonder why this produces an auto-released NSArray - with a copy of the data - when there is absolutely no need for it..